# Auto focus inside model popup not working on live

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I am new in php development and also sorry if this question is already asked in stack. I am getting trouble in auto focus inside model popup input field.

Following is my code i am applying, it is working in local host but not in live . Please help

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('input[type="text"]').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have jquery library imported on live?

Comment: and is it accessible?

Comment: Have you checked the console for JS errors?

Comment: yes its implemented

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) i found this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using show.bs.modal , before you must create a event modal show , then you can use show.bs.modal , try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
});

$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```